# Android ContentProvider with Room

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-room

I'm trying to use ContentProvider and Room. I try to learn from this sample: [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceContentProviderSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/contentprovidersample/provider/SampleContentProvider.java).

It allows to either get all cheeses or get cheese by id like this:

```
...
CheeseDao cheese = SampleDatabase.getInstance(context).cheese();
final Cursor cursor;
if (code == CODE_CHEESE_DIR) {
   cursor = cheese.selectAll();
} else {
   cursor = cheese.selectById(ContentUris.parseId(uri));
}
cursor.setNotificationUri(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
return cursor;
...
```

I clearly don't understand much what is going on... There are two codes: CODE_CHEESE_DIR and CODE_CHEESE_ITEM that should probably somehow define what query will be made, but they are private and used like this:

```
final int code = MATCHER.match(uri);
if (code == CODE_PLACE_DIR || code == CODE_PLACE_ITEM){
...
```

If I get it right, ContentProvider is somehow accessed through CursorLoader.

```
CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),
             SampleContentProvider.URI_CHEESE,
             new String[]{Cheese.COLUMN_NAME},
             null, null, null);
```

I don't see where I specify what I want to select. How would I go about querying item by id? What if I needed a range of ids?

Comment: It feels like you should not be bothering with a `ContentProvider`. Many apps do not need one, and most of those that do are sharing files via `FileProvider`, not a database. Why do you feel that you should be implementing a `ContentProvider`?

Comment: You are probably right. It's most likely way out of my league. Originally I was looking for info about when to open/close SQLite database. I read somewhere that if you use a ContentProvider right you have only one connection to database and you don't really have to worry about it's opening and closing. I probably wouldn't use it right anyway though.

Comment: "I read somewhere that if you use a ContentProvider right you have only one connection to database and you don't really have to worry about it's opening and closing" -- the typical solution is to never close the database. Close it if it is convenient to do so, and you're certain that nothing else will be using the database anymore. Frequently, our apps are complex enough that we cannot be 100% certain that the database is safe to close at any point. Since there is no harm in not closing the database, we often do not worry about it.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I was worried about leaking database, but use of singleton should be sufficient for that. Other advantages of ContentProvider looked like a nice bonus, but the added complexity isn't worth it for me at this point, you are right about that :)